# drag image in canvas with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new in html5 canvas. I dont understand why reason the image don't move near the mouse, when click on image, the image moves several pixel under the mouse, this is my javacript code

```
var pressed=false;

var mousex=0,mousey=0;
function pressMous(){
  pressed=true;
}
var prevX=0,prevY=0;
function movemouse(evt){
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  if(pressed){
     mousex=evt.clientX - rect.left;
    mousey=evt.clientY - rect.top;
    updateImagen();
  }
}
function upmouse(){
  pressed=false;
}
var ima;

var  radianes = Math.PI/180;
var image = new Image();
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',pressMous,false); canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',movemouse,false); canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',upmouse,false);

paint();

/*********/
var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;
/*****************/

function updateImagen() {

        ctx.save();

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        console.log("mousex "+mousex+" mousey " +mousey);

 ctx.drawImage(image, mousex, mousey, image.width, image.height);

        ctx.restore();
    }

function paint(){
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //image.src = "https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/logo_catalog/glyph_2016-vfl3-TV2d.svg";
image.src = "https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/images/index/animation-strips/static-images/work-on-slides-together-vfligazGL.png";

    image.onload = function () {
        var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
        cxt.drawImage(image,canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2);
}

}
```

And this is my jsfiddle, i don't know this behaviour
https://jsfiddle.net/93x8209b/

Comment: All is true. It should be understood that the coordinates transferred to the `left` and `top` of the object create indents from the upper left corner.

Comment: ... you know the image you are using has a quite a bit of transparent padding space surrounding the actual image right? You will need to create a new version of the image without that transparent space or adjust your calculations to take it into affect if you want it to be under / closer to the cursor

Comment: You are right! I was seeing other examples like this http://jsfiddle.net/LAS8L/952/ and i I did not understand because this happened to me